# How to code the OnStart function for windows service program?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-services

I created a service in Visual C++. Installed it using `instsrv.exe` and `srvany.exe`.
When I check at the Services applet in Control Panel, the service is registered. But when I want to start it, this message appears:

```
the service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some service stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example the  Performance logs and Alert Service.
```

I just have this code inside my OnStart function:

```
(void)system("C:\ReleaseExe\Example1Server.exe");
```

I my code correct? Or is there any other way to code it to make sure that the service can be in running state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that exe you are starting up is actually your service, this is the wrong way to do it.

The Windows Service Control Manager (SCM) actually calls into your service's EXE via defined entry points - you need to provide the logic to do what your particular service needs in those entry points, including notifying the SCM of state changes in your service (STOPPED-> RUNNING, RUNNING->STOPPED, and so on).

Read the background info on MSDN, starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685967%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), for clarification of what you must provide.  Note that `OnStart` is specific to implementing Services in managed code, you won't be doing it that way in Visual C++.  Perhaps C# would be an easier route?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. My exe is my simple RPC server. So far the RPC server works when I call it using the console.

Comment: What will happen here then is that `OnStart` will not get called.  You need instead to code up Service Entry Point, ServiceMain, and Service Control Handler as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685967(v=VS.85).aspx.  In any case you don't need to execute your process yourself using `system` - that's what the SCM does.